# onClick() trigger not working on Firebase webapp

Tags: javascript, html, css, firebase

Recently I started working with HTML and created a Firebase web app. I used Codepen to create a basic project in which an image element (the cookie) was tied to an onClick() event. It worked. I then uploaded it to Firebase and tried running it, and it didn't work.

**HTML**

```
<html>
<title>Aries - Cookie Clicker</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />
<script src="main.js"></script>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images/favicon.ico"/>
  <h1>Cookie Clicker </h1>
  <div>
    <img id="cookie" src="http://pngimg.com/uploads/cookie/cookie_PNG13656.png" ondragstart="return false;"/>
  </div>
  
  <div id="scoresection">
    <div class="scoretext">
      <h2 id="counter">+1</h2>
      <h2> Cookies Clicked: </h2>
      <p id="score" class="numbers">0</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <button onclick="resetClick()">Reset</button>
```

**CSS**

```
  width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
}

.numbers{
  font-size: 60px;
}

#scoresection{
  width: 600px;
  margin: auto;
}

body{
  font-family: arial;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url("https://media.giphy.com/media/BHNfhgU63qrks/giphy.gif");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  color: white;
  cursor: crosshair;
}

#counter{
  visibility: hidden;
  position: relative; left: 200px; bottom: 200px;
  font-size: 40px;
  animation-name: plusOne;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
}

@keyframes plusOne{
  from{left: 200px; bottom: 200px;}
  to{left: 200px; bottom: 300px;}
}

button{
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

cookie.pointer{
  cursor: pointer;
}

#reset{
  cursor: pointer
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
var cookie = document.getElementById("cookie");
var points = 0;
var counter = document.getElementById("counter")

cookie.onclick = addClick;

function addClick() {
  points += 1;
  score.innerHTML = points;
  counter.style.visibility = 'visible';
}

reset.onClick = resetClick;

function resetClick() {
  location.reload();
}
```

As you can probably see, its pretty simple but some help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: `reset.onClick` - Did you check this line ? It should be `onclick`

Comment: I am not sure what was working in previous and now not working. You said you uploaded to firebase, this means you hosted your project to firebase hosting? And which button's click event is not working? Please specify so that i can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have copied your code in my side and there was needed to update code.

1. First you should include javascript code under the elements are placed.
   Browser will compile script from first to end in one flow so the order is essential to catch element in code.
2. You don't have to link onclick to resetbutton by javascript because it has been already tied up to onclick event when reset button has been defined.

And you should keep typical html form as some tags are missing in your code.
So you should update html code like below.

```
<html>
<title>Aries - Cookie Clicker</title>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images/favicon.ico"/>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Cookie Clicker </h1>
  <div>
    <img id="cookie" src="http://pngimg.com/uploads/cookie/cookie_PNG13656.png" ondragstart="return false;"/>
  </div>
  
  <div id="scoresection">
    <div class="scoretext">
      <h2 id="counter">+1</h2>
      <h2> Cookies Clicked: </h2>
      <p id="score" class="numbers">0</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button onclick="resetClick()">Reset</button>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have deployed it to firebase hosting and it works!
https://mytest-beb7e.web.app/

Comment: The thing is clicking the cookie is not working. Clicking the reset button works fine.

Comment: Ok then can you please send me live firebase webapp url? OnLocal it is working though.

Comment: As I see you placed <script src="main.js"></script> before <div> has defined. As I explained in answer you should place it under all elements are defined.

Comment: @AriesNinja I updated answer. You please upload to firebase hosting and try again.

Comment: I have deployed to firebase hosting. https://mytest-beb7e.web.app/ it works

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help! My code still does not work, but I have the feeling my structure is messed up somehow.

Do you think there is anything that might be missing?

Here is an image showing my file structure: https://prnt.sc/vjmacd

Comment: @AriesNinja as I see your screenshot you have js file name as code.js.  This maybe js file that you imported in index.html? Then you should rename that to main.js since you import main.js.

Comment: yes, I actually found this issue a while ago and can now close this thread. Just reply telling me you've read this. Thanks!

Comment: @AriesNinja its good to hear you fixed this issue. please vote up my answer if you can. Actually it is simple solution so I am quite feeling not enough, ask any question if you have more thanks. :)